# Laravel - Open a blade view in ckeditor and save the source code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to implement a feature in my newsletter app for admin, so that when the admin opens a tab "Create New Email" he gets this page where he can make a new email or paste some text with styling from Word or whatever.
[image: ckeditor]

I don't know how to save that file in Laravel as a view like other pages inside views/emails folder in format *.blade.php, please help

Comment: So you just want to take the HTML generated from the form and save it to a blade file right?

Comment: Yes...and then later i can send it as an email - How to save it???

Comment: One part of question is answered but i still don't know how to load a view (some_file.blade.php) inside ckeditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to take the HTML generated from the form `POST` in your controller and do something simple like:

`file_put_contents(resource_path('views/emails/email.blade.php'), $request->html)`

Obviously you'll need to adjust the above accordingly to reference just the `html` portion.

There is nothing special going on to just name a file that is blade compatible.

If you need dynamic variable/placeholder support it's a little more complicated but still totally doable.

Comment: can you join my chatroom if you have time http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120609/laravel

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it better by saving that content to database and next send it using email template.

For example take a look:

```
Mail::send('emails.email-template', ['data' => $data], function ($m) use ($data) {
    $m->from('your@email.com', $data['name']);
    $m->replyTo($data['email'], $data['name']);
    $m->to($data['to'])->subject($data['subject']);
});
```

And your email template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
{!! $data['content'] !!}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for though.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to save into database the input from CKEditor. This way you can edit / delete / create variants.

You can do it this way :
1. Create a form with CKEditor, the form has to use the POST method

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/email/store">

<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="email_content" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
        This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
    </textarea>
    <script>
        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
        // instance, using default configuration.
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>
</div>
```

2. Create a controller to store this value

The route to trigger the controller:

```
Route::post('/admin/email/store', 'EmailController@store');
```

The controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $email= new Email;
        $email->email_content = $request->email_content;
        $email->save();
        return back();
}
```

In this example, I assume that you have created the Email model with at least a column 'email_content'. You can have other columns such as 'email_title' that you could populate from the form.